# jenkins deletes existing work space ,when trying to clone new git repo from git scm plugin

Tags: git, jenkins

I see in a Jenkins job log:

```
Cloning the remote Git repository ssh://username@systemname.eu.company.com:29418/<repo-name>.
ERROR: Failed to clean the workspace Java.io.IOException: Unable to delete ‘C:\Users\<usersname>\GitRepositorys\reponame’. 
  Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
Error cloning remote repo ‘origin’ Hudson.plugins.git.GitException:
  Failed to delete workspace
```

This above error we had got, but it had already deleted the majority of files and only files which where active was not deleted.
And no delete workspace or clean up command was active in jenkins job configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to see if there is any process preempting those files (and blocking the deletion). Use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> "find process" feature.

Sometimes, I have to reboot the slave server in order to make sure those processes go away.

Then retry your job, and see if the workspace can be deleted then.

Comment: Hi Von. I am not able to understand why it's trying to deleting the work space.

Comment: @prakyathshetty Not sure: it seems to be a bug in progress (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15852), which would be fixed in Jenkins 2.7.x (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22795). What version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: jenkins 2.7.2 version ,git plugin 3.0.1

Comment: @prakyathshetty would a Jenkins 2.46.3 LTS and a Git plugin 3.3.0 work better?